# Oauth2 deployment on WebLogic 12c - 401 Authorization error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, weblogic

I have implemented oAuth2 on Spring Boot to call other services and everything works fine from in built Spring Boot Tomcat server. I'm able to successfully call other services.

However when I try to deploy the application on WebLogic 12c, I am getting 401 authorization. Upon some research, I thought I found a solution by disabling WebLogic own authentication by including below line in config.xml.

```
<enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>false</enforce-valid-basic-auth-credentials>
```

However, our company WebLogic admins didn't agree to this solution as it could be flagged by GIS due to security risk.

It is possible I will have to find another way to reimplement this.